# If we let B be a subset of A, where |A|=n,|B|=k. What is the number of all subsets of A whose intersection with B has X element?

Tags: combinatorics

I know when the number of all subsets of A whose intersection with B has x=1 element, the answer would be $${k} 2^{n-k} $$ but what about when x =2 ?? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $X\subseteq A$, and $|X\cap B|=2$. There are $\binom{k}2$ ways to choose $2$ elements of $B$ to be the two elements of $X\cap B$. The rest of $X$ can be any subset of $A\setminus B$, so the final answer is ... ?